# MySQL INSERT INTO... SELECT - How to determine which select clauses result in NULL?

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I'm trying to insert a row into a table which references keys in other tables. There are instances where the insert/select will fail because the selected value can not be null.  I'd like to know which selects fail so that I can create the necessary rows in other tables as needed.

The following example is a bit contrived, but should illustrate the challenge here:

```
CREATE TABLE TableOne
(
  TableOneId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Value VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE TableTwo
(
  TableTwoId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Value VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE DependentTable
(
  DependentId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  TableOneId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  TableTwoId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  Value FLOAT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (TableOneId) REFERENCES TableOne(TableOneId),
  FOREIGN KEY (TableTwoId) REFERENCES TableOne(TableTwoId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO DependentTable (Value, TableOneId, TableTwoId) SELECT 1.0, TableOne.TableOneId, TableTwo.TableTwoId FROM TableOne,TableTwo WHERE TableOne.Value='TableOneValue' AND TableTwo.Value='TableTwoValue';

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

If either 'TableOneValue' or 'TableTwoValue' doesn't exist, then the select will return null and 0 rows will be inserted - as expected.  However, I was hoping to get some other piece of information that would allow me to determine which value didn't exist so I can create it.

The problem, at least in my actual situation, is that blindly creating each value to satisfy the foreign key reference would be overkill/expensive as there are multiple foreign keys and some of those dependent tables will have other required dependencies.  I'd like to approach it a little more intelligently and determine which reference(s) didn't exist and only create those instead.

I could try to create the rows in dependent tables one-by-one, wait until a row is actually inserted ( versus getting a duplicate entry ), and then try the original insert again - but it feels like there should be a better/more elegant way to do this...

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd do is insert everything into an intermediate table without the Foreign Keys.  Then use that table to query against TableOne and TableTwo, to see which items in TableOneId and TableTwoId do not exist in TableOne and TableTwo.  Then adjust, cleanup, etc.

`INSERT INTO IntermediateTable(DependentId,
  TableOneId,
  TableTwoId,
  Value) blah blah blah`

The following will show you the missing values (repeat for TableTwo):

`SELECT *
FROM IntermediateTable i 
LEFT JOIN TableOne t1 ON t1.TableOneid = i.TableOneId
WHERE t1.TableOneId IS NULL`

When cleanup is done, you can copy everything from the intermediate table into DependentTable with foreign keys defined.

`INSERT INTO DependentTable SELECT * FROM IntermediateTable` --everything has been cleaned up so that there are now no missing ids in TableOne and TableTwo.

Without this intermediate table, you lack something to use for a query against TableOne and TableTwo for undefined ids.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - the more I think about your solution, the more I like it. It definitely answers my question.

Comment: I do like the answer, but I'm curious to see if any other interesting answers are provided before I accept it.